# Is there a safety issue if my window AC causes lights to dim?

Tags: electrical, hvac

I've been researching this fairly common problem. However I haven't found any solutions.

When my 12,000 BTU window AC first starts, the compressor it will whine for 3-5 seconds during which the lights will dim. Occasionally it will take 2-3 tries to start with a few seconds between attempts, until it finally starts. Once it starts it runs without any issues.

I'm on a 15amp circuit with lights, and a home office behind a UPS-battery.

- How worried do I need to be about the dimming, and failure to start?
- What can be done to help the AC unit start?

I see some suggestions to put this on its own circuit. Is this the only way? If it's a short term boost in energy need is there some sort of capacitor I can add to get the AC over the cold start?

My older 8,000 BTU does not have this issue, and I'm thinking of down-sizing.

Comment: Have you checked the capacitor in the 12000 BTU unit?.

Comment: It sounds like it might be using everything a 15 amp circuit has to give.  Start up can be two or three times the running power/amps/watts.  Would find the amps/watts for the AC and add two or three for the other stuff(lights,office) and see if it is at 12 or more amps, should keep to 12 or below for 15 amp circuit.

Comment: The failed starts sounds more like a mechanical problem.

Comment: How old is the 12,000 btu A/C?

Comment: since they store DC, a capacitor would not help with AC. They are used to help start AC motors by leveling out spikes of current in the low milliseconds range, not to provide several seconds of reserve power.

Comment: Can you estimate how far the home office is from the power company's electric meter?  Are you familiar with "Volts" and "Amps"?  Any chance you can take voltage measurements or buy a $20 "Kill-a-Watt" energy monitor? (just for the voltage readings).

Comment: Window AC is 1 year old, https://www.lg.com/us/air-conditioners/lg-LW1217ERSM-window-air-conditioner. 
Distance from "office" to panel is under 50 feet, assuming the outlet in use is the first.
It looks like there is an internal capacitor in the unit, which I can try to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a safety issue if my window AC causes lights to dim?

Not usually, no. This is normal with high draw startup items like A/Cs, vacuums, and microwaves.

The bigger issue is having sensitive electronics running on that circuit because you are essentially creating a brown-out and can fry your expensive devices over time: TV, computer, etc...

> When my 12,000 BTU window AC first starts, the compressor it will whine for 3-5 seconds during which the lights will dim.

Sounds almost normal.

> Occasionally it will take 2-3 tries to start with a few seconds between attempts, until it finally starts.

That's a certified yikes from me. Sounds like the compressor might be old or seized and is having an issue overcoming the mechanical resistance. I'm a little surprised it hasn't started smoking yet.

Answer (score 1):

A 12000 BTU AC unit will, depending on its efficiency, consume 1200-1500 Watts.  At 120V, which I assume you are using here, that will take 10-12.5 A more or less.

Since your circuit is rated for 15A and there are likely other devices on that same circuit, namely the ones that are dimming, you are probably very close to the capacity of that circuit.

It should be safe from a wiring perspective assuming that your wiring is code-compliant and your circuit breaker is actually 15A and is working as it should.

But it's possible that you are damaging your AC unit and possibly other devices on the same circuit due to low voltage.  The motors that run AC units are almost always AC induction motors and a characteristic of these is that they will draw the same amount of POWER regardless of the voltage.  So when there is excess current the voltage will drop but the motor will pull more current.  In an idea world this would not matter but for us real world folks the extra current causes extra heat to be generated in the motor which can cause damage over time.

Your best bet would be to get a dedicated line installed for the AC or, as you noted, downsize to the 8000 BTU unit to give yourself some additional "cushion" on that circuit's capacity.

Comment: An alternative to running a new circuit (expensive) or downgrading (possibly not cold enough), would be to find a lightly used 15A circuit or a 20A circuit which would have more overhead for the AC to use and leave something for the other devices plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by others, this is quite typical due to the total power usage.

> I'm on a 15amp circuit with lights, and a home office behind a UPS-battery.

I have a similar situation. In my case though, it is the laser printers (I only use one at a time) that causes the dimming and other problems. My solution was to put all of the computer equipment, except the printers, on a UPS. Often, though not always, at the start of a print job the UPS will kick in for a few seconds. That isn't ideal but protects the sensitive and expensive equipment from damage. Lighting and most other equipment on the circuit isn't bothered by the momentary voltage dip.

In my case, running a new circuit to split the loads would be easy if I had space on the panel, which I don't have. (Waiting on electrician to do the heavy-up and replace the old panels.) Based on lots of questions here, for many people simply running the cable for a new circuit would cost a lot, aside from panel issues, but that really is the best permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

### NO. You have a serious wiring problem.

The behavior of the motor and the failed starts indicates voltage is plunging very, very low - and I would expect the UPS to be kicking in to protect your computer.

Here's the thing. Circuits (of normal length) have a safety limit of 15 or 20 *amperes* aka amps. However, they can carry a LOT more amps than that without anywhere near the voltage drop needed to stall a motor.

As an example say you have a 50' circuit with #14 wire. You have 124V at the meter (common), and you pull 50 amps on that 15 amp circuit.  In that case voltage will sag but only to 111.4 volts - heck that's still more than 110V, with a more than 3 times overload! (mind you the wires will glow cherry red and set the house on fire if you ran them that way any length of time).

So **the problem is NOT you overloading the circuit**. That might be a problem also, and if so you should fix it - but it's not causing *this*.

So your voltage is crashing, for one of three likely reasons.

### Lost Neutral (or live)

This is the great one, because it's a huge problem that threatens your whole house, and fixing it is free.

This is caused by a break in [the 3 wires coming from the utility](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=264).

If the "Neutral" wire breaks, it will cause wild swings in voltage - and the A/C trying to start will crash the voltage on the "pole" of power the A/C unit is on, and raise the voltage on the other pole (and the appliances there might not like power suddenly leaping up to 190 volts).  If you have had other appliances mysteriously burn out, this is what's doing it.

If one of the "hot / pole" wires breaks, then half your breakers will go dead *until your water heater cycles on*. Then, the water heater's resistance will feed the dead group from the live group, via its internal resistance - which means voltage will sag. When the A/C tries to start, it will sag *a lot*.  You can test this by turning off all 240V breakers (the weird ones, see video) and see if half the house loses power entirely when you do.

The lost neutral is extremely subtle -  here we have 8 cottages sharing a single service, and when we all lost our neutral, it took a week to *realize it*.  The lineman also spotted where a neighbor had a broken hot wire, the neighbor said "Well, I just turned on the stove when I wanted those sockets to work".  *facepalm*

### Faulty internal wiring

This could be a bunch of different things.  The most obvious is a poor connection that is adding a lot of resistance to the circuit.  (and adding a lot of HEAT to that location, possible to start a fire).

It's too broad a topic to really narrow down with what you have said.  A good "once-over" of all circuit connections may be called for.

### Very long wire run from meter to your home office

We are talking hundreds of feet here.  With COVID and all, people have been building sheds and outbuildings and putting working space in them.  It's common to run a simple 15A or 20A circuit hundreds of feet to these buildings, "just to run lights or tool chargers".

When length of a 120V circuit gets above about 90', the installer needs to think about "voltage drop" - and if necessary, enlarge the wire to compensate. The larger wire will have less voltage drop.  But often this is ignored (especially by DIYers) or the person balks at paying for the wire that is actually necessary and hopes it will work with smaller wire.

I frequently see home-power projects fail because of the latter reason.  Can't argue with physics.  Any wiring length over 100' deserves a recalculation.  And if the calculation reveals that the proper copper wire would be prohibitively priced, come talk to us - we have a really good solution for that!